# Laravel, FatalErrorException

Tags: php

Im new to Laravel so im trying to follow a totorial on youtube. When I try to run the site, I keep getting a FatalErrorException.

I tryed to go thruogh the totorial again, startet a new project and looked around online but cant find a solution.

I have attached a screenshot of the error so hope there are someone who can help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your route link. Place a `'` after `class` like this:

`array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')`

In fact, your screenshot gives all the information you need. The exact error and even the lines where the error is.

You can read more about syntax errors (and how to solve them) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18050072/590877).

Comment: I figured the answer was to be found in the screenshot, but simply could not find it. Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the single quotes.

array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')

As a programmer you should check your program thoroughly,this forum is not to solve the syntax or type mistake problems